# Why does sys.argv print path and why does it not open input in console?

Tags: python

I am learning Python for an exam and honestly I am spending more time with fixing some system settings than with coding.
Here is the next issue (MacOS):

```
import sys
v0=float(sys.argv[1])
t=float(sys.argv[2])
g=9.81
y=v0*t -0.5*g*t**2
print(t,y)
```

sys.argv doesn´t work. When I ask for the len(argv) it prints out 1. And when I print sys.argv[0] it prints the path of my file. Which is as far as I understand not what I want. So please tell what is wrong here?

I get the following error:

```
v0=float(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Best regards

Comment: Are you actually passing any command line arguments to your script?

Comment: How are you running your code? Check the documentation for [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) - it always places the script name in index 0, and subsequent arguments in indices 1...n. If you're only running your code as `python3 script.py` then you don't have any args.

Comment: What were you *expecting* `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` to contain?  Where were you expecting those values to come from?

Comment: Hi, no I do not. And I looked in my book. That seems to be what I am not understanding. How do I pass command line arguments to my script?

Comment: To be honest, the example is explained badly and I don´t really understand what they want to teach me. That´s why I feel quite lost right now and unable to answer competently.

Comment: You're probably running your code as `python3 script.py`, which has no arguments. If you ran `python3 script.py 1 2`, you now have two arguments - `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` would be `"1"` and `"2"`, respectively. I wanted o link you to Python's tutorial documentation about arguments, but it's honestly quite barebones and doesn't explain more than we're doing right here.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand better now. For this to work I would need to start a script from the command line e.g. test.py 5.0 6.0

Comment: Yes, exactly, try that and your script should work (from my very cursory glance it looks correct otherwise).

Comment: Out of curiosity -- where were you expecting the values for `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` to come from?

Comment: You can learn (a lot) more [here](https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments/).

Comment: @jasonharper and John Gordon: to be honest I expected anything. I am trying to figure out how sys.argv is used.

Comment: Okay, I think I have found the issue. I was opening the script in the PyCharme console and not in the terminal. But now I seem to be doing something wrong in the terminal. I paste in the path of the file but it doesn´t give me permission.


(base) username@Air-von-Thoms ~ % /Users/username/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Part1.py
zsh: permission denied: /Users/username/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Part1.py

Comment: By default, your scripts aren't executable without some additional steps - you'd have to set the execution bit (`chmod +x`) and specify the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). To run your script right now, you have to preface your script with the `python3` executable, like: `python3 /Users/username/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Part1.py`